# Assigning Static IPv6 address to Ubuntu VM in Vmware

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, ipv6

I'm trying to assign a static ipv6 address to a ubuntu vm running on VMWare.

At the moment, I've got a single network adapter, a NAT.

/etc/network/interfaces is configured like this (following [this](http://jochen.kirstaetter.name/blog/linux/configure-ipv6-on-ubuntu.html) guys advice) :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
# IPv4 configuration
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.2
  network 192.168.1.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255

# IPv6 configuration
iface eth0 inet6 static
  pre-up modprobe ipv6
  address 2001:db8:bad:a55::2
  netmask 64
```

However, after restarting, my eth0 interface is down. When I bring it up manually ifconfig only gives this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:34:3f:24  
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe34:3f24/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1164 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:478 (478.0 B)
```

I have no internet connectivity but the link address can be pinged from the host or other vms.

The goal is to have a VM that is globally routable from other machines (host, other vms, other computers...) with a well known IPv6 address that does not change.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When playing with IPv6 it is commonly recommended to use the `ip` utility from the iproute2 package.

Comment: I have no idea how the VMware host or the guests reacts if you try to configure a static IPv6 address on a NATed interface. I could image that the configuration script fails altogether and takes the link down - do the system logs say anything? Invoke the `/etc/init.d`-script manually and see what happens.